# OpenMP - Why is firstprivate causing an error?

Tags: c, openmp

Why am I getting this error, and what should I do?

```
error: firstprivate variable 'j' is private in outer context

void foo() {
    int i;
    int j = 10;
    #pragma omp for firstprivate(j)
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        printf("%d\n", j);
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It works if you use the pragma

```
#pragma omp parallel for firstprivate(j)
```

Note that `omp for` and `omp parallel for` aren't the same thing: the latter is shorthand for an `omp for` inside an `omp parallel`.

Answer (score 1):

I deleted my first answer because I missed something and it was incorrect.  The error is correct because of a restriction in the OpenMP V3.0 spec (and previous versions), section 2.9.3.4 firstprivate clause, Restrictions bullet 2:

> • A list item that is private within a parallel region must not appear in a
>   firstprivate clause on a worksharing construct if any of the worksharing
>   regions arising from the worksharing construct ever bind to any of the parallel
>   regions arising from the parallel construct.

The problem is that it doesn't know which private value to use among the threads that are to execute the worksharing region.  If it is a new parallel region, then each thread will create a new region and the firstprivate is copied from the private copy of the thread creating the region.

Comment: In my experience, GCC tends to support OpenMP 1.0 + different subsets of 2.0, depending on the version. I tested my answer with GCC.

Comment: It's been almost 9 years but I still want to ask: where do you see the **parallel region** arising from the **parallel construct**? In the original code, there is no parallel construct (there is implicit parallel region but no construct).